# ActiveRecord: Pass class instead of string to class_name when defining associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

Are there any implications or gotchas to passing in a class instead of a string when defining an association?

```
belongs_to :owner, class_name: User
```

As opposed to:

```
belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User"
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The class may not be loaded yet in which case you'll get a `NameError: uninitialized constant User`.

You're supposed to use `"User"` for this reason, as implied by the option name: `:class_name`, not `:class`.

Comment: Or the symbol `:user`.  Adding for completeness.

Comment: @Josh, shouldn't it be `:User` with a capital *u*?

Comment: @meagar shouldn't the class be loaded by rails' autoloading?

Comment: The [docs](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/130dd3da2a2c557185a73afa9e67138691c8e32f/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb#L15050) also use a string, for reference.

Answer (score 0):

In rare case I encounter some random errors when using classes (User) instead of class name as a string ('User'). I am unable to reproduce them and solve this just by restarting app server.

> It can be also a symbol. It cannot be a class constant because if you have two associated models, when the first is being loaded, the second is not yet defined, so the constant would not be defined, and this would give an error.

Source: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6486