# How are I18n and database ActiveRecord querying related?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through, rails-i18n

Does anyone know, what does I18n have to do with database?

```
class DecorativeCentersSalesRepresentative < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :decorative_center, class_name: ::DecorativeCenter
  belongs_to :user, class_name: ::SalesRepresentative
end

class DecorativeCenter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :decorative_centers_sales_representative
  has_many :sales_representatives,
    through: :decorative_centers_sales_representative
end

class SalesRepresentative < User
  has_many :decorative_centers_sales_representative,
    foreign_key: :user_id
  has_many :decorative_centers,
    through: :decorative_centers_sales_representative,
    foreign_key: :user_id
end
```

All is good, and I can do

```
SalesRepresentative.last.decorative_centers
  SalesRepresentative Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`type` IN ('SalesRepresentative')  ORDER BY `users`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  DecorativeCenter Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `decorative_centers`.* FROM `decorative_centers` INNER JOIN `decorative_centers_sales_representative` ON `decorative_centers`.`id` = `decorative_centers_sales_representative`.`decorative_center_id` WHERE `decorative_centers_sales_representative`.`user_id` = 4
#=> [#<DecorativeCenter:0x000000088e5578]
```

But when I do

```
DecorativeCenter.last.sales_representatives
  DecorativeCenter Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `decorative_centers`.* FROM `decorative_centers`  ORDER BY `decorative_centers`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
#=> I18n::InvalidLocale: :en is not a valid locale
#=> from /home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@profill-base/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n.rb:284:in `enforce_available_locales!'
```

WHY??

I know it is an invalid locale, valid one is `:pl`:

```
I18n.available_locales
#=> [:pl]
I18n.default_locale
#=> :pl
```

But how are these things even related and why can I query one way, and can not other?

Comment: The Rails I18n module does not really have anything to do with the database - rather you have something which is causing a lookup when the `ActiveRecord::Collection` is being initialized. However its impossible to tell why without a stack trace.

Comment: @max updated the question with reallife code, thx for taking a look

Comment: @AndreyDeineko - Do you get those errors in console? If so it might be related to the inspect method.

Comment: The only obvious thing I see is that `has_many :decorative_centers_sales_representative` is not properly pluralized. Use `decorative_centers_sales_representatives`.

Comment: @BroiSatse Yea, these methods are from console

Comment: @max this should not be the reason, we decided to name the join table business-wise. I could try changing the name, but it should not matter

Comment: @AndreyDeineko - Try running `DecorativeCenter.last.sales_representatives && nil` -  it will prevent calling inspect on the resulting object. If there is no exception, you know it is `inspect` that causing the issue. Do you have more of the stack trace there?

Comment: @BroiSatse unfortunately the same error..

Comment: @AndreyDeineko - do you have any more stacktrace then?

Comment: I wish I had.. The only thing I have is the one that I've posted

Comment: I would fix the pluralization thing unless you need to work with a legacy database - you'll get a bunch of issues with constant lookup unless you set up a special inflection.

Comment: @max changed, but unfortunately to no avail..

Comment: @AndreyDeineko - Interesting. That would mean it fails on building the relation, as the command wouldn't even go to the database. Can you load the other association? `DecorativeCenter.last.decorative_centers_sales_representative`

Comment: @max yeah, this is working correctly. I found an issue, it is because `SalesRepresentative` inherits from `User` (STI), and I had to specify the `class_name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time of debugging I have found the real issue.

[Starting from the end](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb#L87):

```
  class HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError < ActiveRecordError #:nodoc:
    def initialize(reflection = nil)
      if reflection
        through_reflection      = reflection.through_reflection
        source_reflection_names = reflection.source_reflection_names
        source_associations     = reflection.through_reflection.klass._reflections.keys
        super("Could not find the source association(s) #{source_reflection_names.collect(&:inspect).to_sentence(:two_words_connector => ' or ', :last_word_connector => ', or ', :locale => :en)} in model #{through_reflection.klass}. Try 'has_many #{reflection.name.inspect}, :through => #{through_reflection.name.inspect}, :source => <name>'. Is it one of #{source_associations.to_sentence(:two_words_connector => ' or ', :last_word_connector => ', or ', :locale => :en)}?")
      else
        super("Could not find the source association(s).")
      end
    end
  end
```

In this error locales were hardcoded, and it is `:en`, that is why I could not even get the error message.

1) In my app `:en` was not within available locales, so in order to get the error message Rails was tying to spit out, I temporarily set the app's locale to `:en`.

2) Now I could get the error:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) "sales_representative" or :sales_representatives in model DecorativeCentersSalesRepresentatives. Try 'has_many :sales_representatives, :through => :decorative_centers_sales_representatives, :source => <name>'. Is it one of versions, decorative_center, or user?
```

Which simply states, that I was wrong in writing belongs_to in my join table.

AR expects the name of an association to be defined, not a table in database.

So changing

```
# (STI) table users, but AR model is called SalesRepresentative 
belongs_to :user, class_name: ::SalesRepresentative
```

to

```
# changed to real AR table name passing the foreign_key
belongs_to :sales_representative, class_name: ::SalesRepresentative, foreign_key: :user_id
```

made it work as expected.

Comment: Nice, however you usually use a string for class name and not the class itself. `class_name: "DecorativeCenter::SalesRepresentative"`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20390991/activerecord-pass-class-instead-of-string-to-class-name-when-defining-associati

Comment: How was that causing I18n issue?

Comment: @BroiSatse, in fact this solution worked only for a day, and somehow it was not working later, so I had to degub hard(er) :) I'll update the answer with real solution.